# Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_STRING token

Tags: java, json, arraylist, jackson

I have looked for other post in stack overflow but none of them work for me. Here is the piece of code:

```
 public class Forward implements Serializable {
  private List<String> freq;
  public List<String> getFreq() {
    System.out.println("Print Freq::: -->  " + freq);
    return freq;
  }

  public void setFreq(List<String> freq) {
    this.freq = freq;
 }
}
```

The JSON string is:

```
{"forward":[{"freq":"78000000"}]}
```

My mapper is:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();            
mapper.configure(DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY, true);
String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(result);
```

If I remove List freq and change to String freq it works but my JSON can contain one or more freq so I need to create a List.I get exception as:

```
  Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of VALUE_STRING token at [Source: org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.ReaderInterceptorExecutor$UnCloseableInputStream
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`DeserializationFeature.ACCEPT_SINGLE_VALUE_AS_ARRAY` works fine in order to deserialize `"freq":"78000000"` fragment as value of `List<String> freq` list.

But you have another problem: your `json` contains explicit array of `forward`. In order to deserialize this entire `json` you need to have some kind of wrapper class, say:

```
  public class ForwardWrapper {
        private List<Forward> forward;

        public List<Forward> getForward() {
            return forward;
        }

        public void setForward(List<Forward> forward) {
            this.forward = forward;
        }
    }
```

In this case

```
    ForwardWrapper fw = mapper.readValue("{\"forward\":[{\"freq\":\"78000000\"}]}", ForwardWrapper.class);
```

will deserialize it perfectly.

Comment: I have a class as PlanList, which has code:                                                     public class PlanList implements Serializable {
  
    private List<Forward> forward;        //getter //setter }      in line String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(result);         result is nothing but        PlanList object.